# Is there a specific way to PING search engines with urls (like pingler.com)?

Tags: php

Is there a standard variable that should be passed to the ping agents?

I'm trying to create my own but I'm not exactly sure how it works.

Is it as simple as appending a REST call to each url or does it need to be in a certain format?

Thanks

**EDIT**

sorry for the bad question description.

Basically I't tring to figure out how pingler.com pings a url to the search engines so that they spiders update the engine results.

Thanks

**EDIT**

thanks guys for the good answers

Comment: I might be the only one, but I really didn't understand what you want

Comment: try edit your post, i did not understand too... you want to know how to ping some domain in your PHP script?

Comment: From the description of pingler, it is a very spammy (and pointless) service. I wouldn't use it or anything like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't. pingler, presumably, has custom code for each search engine it deals with.